# Fluent UI React - About multiple column header in DetailsList

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I want to create multi header like following image using DetailsList of Fluent UI React.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20Y6E.png)

Then, I found [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/11712). That seems the same issue as I facing.

According to the issue's answer, I understood that able to use onRenderDetailsHeader.

However, it doesn't describe concrete how to achieve this.
So I don't know how to implement it in the onRenderDetailsHeader

Is there any sample code or any helpful information to achieve this?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? An example of how to use the property?

Comment: @Nikki9696 Thank you for your advice. I updated the question. Please check it.